# Flutter: Get Provider if exists otherwise return null instead of exception

Tags: flutter, bloc, flutter-provider, flutter-bloc

When we use `BlocProvider.of<OrderBloc>(context)` to access Bloc object, it returns an exception if no `OrderBloc` exists on ancestor widgets of current context. Returned exceptions as follows:

```
No ancestor could be found starting from the context that was passed to BlocProvider.of<OrderBloc>().
```

But I want return `null` instead of exceptions when no `OrderBloc` exists on ancestor widgets. Consider following scenario:

```
var orderBloc = BlocProvider.of<OrderBloc>(context);

return Container(child: orderBloc == null
      ? Text('-')
      : BlocBuilder<OrderBloc, OrderState>(
          bloc: orderBloc,
          builder: (context, state) {
            // build something if orderBloc exists.
          },

        ),          
);
```

Answer (score 7):

You could wrap that line with try/catch like this:

```
var orderBloc;
try {
  orderBloc = BlocProvider.of<OrderBloc>(context);
} catch (e) {}

return Container(child: orderBloc == null
  ? Text('-')
  : BlocBuilder<OrderBloc, OrderState>(
      bloc: orderBloc,
      builder: (context, state) {
        // build something if orderBloc exists.
      },
    ),          
);
```

EDIT:

If you want to reduce the boilerplate:

```
extension ReadOrNull on BuildContext {
  T? readOrNull<T>() {
    try {
      return read<T>();
    } on ProviderNotFoundException catch (_) {
      return null;
    }
  }
}
```

Then your code will be:

```
var orderBloc = context.readOrNull<OrderBloc>();

return Container(child: orderBloc == null
  ? Text('-')
  : BlocBuilder<OrderBloc, OrderState>(
      bloc: orderBloc,
      builder: (context, state) {
        // build something if orderBloc exists.
      },
    ),          
);
```

Comment: I think it should be a more straight way instead of exception handling. I think it could be a common scenario to check a Provider exists or not.

Answer (score 0):

1. find the widget that hold the view model.

   - to make sure there no exception when use BlocProvider.of.
2. if widget exist then to find view model else return null.

```
  static YouViewModel getViewModel(
      BuildContext context) {
    bool isFromSpecifyWidget = false;

    context.visitAncestorElements((element) {
      isFromSpecifyWidget = element.widget is YouWidget;
      return !isFromSpecifyWidget;
    });

    if (isFromSpecifyWidget) {
      return BlocProvider.of<YouViewModel>(context, listen: false);
    }

    return null;
  }
```

Not perfect solution, because you must specify the widget.